# Strange behaviour in Regex, double escape backslash

Tags: regular-expression, indentation

I've tried to debug an indent function i've written, and came over this strange behaviour. Here I try to detect some LateX tags (debug output):

```
>echo previous
\label{ch10.1}
>echo previous =~ "\\label"
1
```

This looks fine. Now i try to do the same thing with the `\begin` tag:

```
>echo previous
\begin{uxlist}
>echo previous =~ "\\begin"
0
```

It somehow works with `\\\\`:

```
>echo previous 
\begin{uxlist}
>echo previous =~ "\\\\begin"
1
```

Which makes no sense at all for me. Is this expected behaviour? If yes I would be rather glad for an explanation.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I solved it by replacing doublequotes with singlequotes.
But it is still strange for example this:

```
>echo previous
  \end{itemize}
>previous =~ "\\item" 
1
>previous =~ "\\end"
0
```

it looks like `\\end` is somehow interpreted as `\e` (Escape) which can not be found. That would mean I had to esacpe each backslash 2 times, which is why it works with 4 backslashes.
But as far as I know, that shouldn't be needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr4) says (scroll down to `expr5 and expr6`):

> The "=~" and "!~" operators match the lefthand argument with the righthand
>   argument, which is used as a pattern.  See pattern for what a pattern is.
>   This matching is always done like 'magic' was set and 'cpoptions' is empty, no
>   matter what the actual value of 'magic' or 'cpoptions' is.  This makes scripts
>   portable.  **To avoid backslashes in the regexp pattern to be doubled, use a
>   single-quote string, see literal-string.**

So this is intended behaviour.

The confusion is caused by the fact that there is no special syntax for regular expressions in Vim's grammar of expressions (like, say, `/regex/` is some languages). This means that Vim reuses its syntax for string literals, which enforces its own set of rules on top of syntax of regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this is inconsistent with `h: expr-quote` where the double backslash is not mentioned. You answered my question without doubt, but if anyone know why it is implemented that way, I would love to hear it.

Comment: When you use `"..."`, you need to escape `\` (and other special characters). Thus, `"\\begin"` becomes `'\begin'`, and as a regex, you now start with the `\b` atom which matches any `<bs>` characters. Thus it won't match the string `\begin{...}`. However, `\l` will match lower case characters, and so `"\\label"` as a regex becomes `\label` which is the same as `[a-z]abel`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg so a doublequoted string gets throught the string processor, and then througth the regex processor or something like that? Even when using `=~` ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, your guess is correct, see my edit.

Comment: @xaizek Thanks you both very much. Now it makes sense for me.

Comment: Note that this is also why it is strongly recommended to _always_ use single quoted strings if possible. Linters (e.g. vint) will warn about unnecessary use of double quoted strings.